# How do i use python to plot fouries series graph?

Tags: python

I have no idea about how to plot fourier series graph from equation like this

[image]

I try to use matplotlib to plot this but there are so many values. Here are code that I used. Not sure about algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_ = np.linspace(0, 30, 10000)

a0 = 3/5
##an = 1/n * np.pi * (np.sin(0.4 * n * np.pi) + np.sin(0.8 * n * np.pi))
##bn = 1/n * np.pi * (2 - np.cos(0.4 * n * np.pi) - np.cos(0.8 * n * np.pi))
f0 = 5

    def a(n):
    return 1/n * np.pi * (np.sin(0.4 * n * np.pi) + np.sin(0.8 * n * np.pi))

def b(n):
    return 1/n * np.pi * (2 - np.cos(0.4 * n * np.pi) - np.cos(0.8 * n * np.pi))

def s(t, n):
    temp = 0
    for i in range (1, n + 1):
        temp = temp + (a(i) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * i * f0 * t) \
         + b(i) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * n * f0 * t))
    temp += a0
    return temp

st = []
for i in range (1, 6):
    st.append(s(1, 6))


plt.title("Test")
plt.plot(x_, st, color="red")
plt.show()
```

Tried this then got this error
`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (5,)`

thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by "so many values"?

Comment: Can you at least give the code with which you tried?

Comment: I thought that wil be multiple x and y because f and t will change and I added my code for you.